# Bootstrap 3 : navbar dropdown menu doesn't disappear when i click else where

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a navbar with a single dropdown menu on the right. When on mobile and I click the toggle button (3 bars) the menu is shown and the icon disappears.

The problem is when I click elsewhere on the page (example: the dummy text), the menu disappears and the icon is still hidden.

What can I do to solve this problem?

An example is available on : https://jsfiddle.net/2eqd8wra/

```
Thank you for your answers
```

Comment: your fiddle working fine, whats your problem ?

Comment: try resizing the output until the 3 bars button appears instead of the user icon, when you click on it, it alerts "showing the menu", click again and it alearts "hiding the menu".  my problem is that when i click on the button to show the menu then click else where on the page the menu dissapear and you can't find it anymore even when you make output screen big again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that i wanted to close dropdown menu dynamicly when i click outside the navbar, i was able to solve this problem by adding a jquery function

```
$('#main-container').click(function (event) {

var _opened = $(".navbar-collapse").hasClass("navbar-collapse") && $(".navbar-collapse").hasClass("in");
if (_opened === true && !($(event.target).hasClass("navbar-toggle"))) {
  $("button.navbar-toggle").click();
}
});
```

This function triggers the click on the navbar button and that solved my problem

Thanks for everyone who tried to help me

Answer (score 0):

..... The problem is when I click elsewhere on the page (example: the dummy text), the menu disappears and the icon is still hidden.....

By referring w3school,use this code , it will solve the problem :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> My Brand</a>
          </div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```